# JfreeBarchart X-axis label position

Tags: java, gwt, charts, bar-chart, jfreechart

I need to display the barchart x-axis label on left side of the starting position of the bar like in below image attached.

I tried the various options avaialble in CategoryLabelPosition, by using these i can able to place the label only like below. but i can't move the label before the actual bar's starting position.

[image]

Tried following code:

```
    CategoryLabelPositions p1 = new CategoryLabelPositions(new 
    CategoryLabelPosition(RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, 
    TextBlockAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT));
    CategoryLabelPosition left = new 
    CategoryLabelPosition(RectangleAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT, 
    TextBlockAnchor.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    final CategoryAxis cAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();cAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.replaceLeftPosition(p1, left));
```

Can you anyone give me idea how to achieve this?